# ebay finding api require access token?

Tags: ebay-api

I am attempting to implement the eBay API and I have taken the steps to create an account, get access token. I submitted the call to obtain an oauth2 access token.

When studying the finding API documentation, it does not mention anything about OAuth2, only that when making calls you should pass your application ID. Does this mean that I do not need to pass an access token or retrieve one when performing calls to the finding API?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you need :

```
api_endpoint
dev_id
app_id
cert_id
runame
auth_token
api_version
```

I am using these credentials detail and it works for me.